# Outline shader break after upgrading to Unity 5.5

Tags: unity-game-engine, fragment-shader

The shader is working fine on unity 5.4 on iPad Air but after upgrading to unity 5.5 it break the outline but the alpha is still working.

> This shader for object support texture and alpha

```
Shader "TFTM/Outline/Basic-Alpha" {
 Properties {
     _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (.5,.5,.5,1)
     _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
 }


SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Transparent" }
     Pass {
         Name "BASE"
         Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
         //Blend DstColor SrcColor
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag
         #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest 
         #include "UnityCG.cginc"
         sampler2D _MainTex;
         float4 _MainTex_ST;
         float4 _Color;
         struct appdata {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
             float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
             float3 normal : NORMAL;
         };

         struct v2f {
             float4 pos : POSITION;
             float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         v2f vert (appdata v)
         {
             v2f o;
             o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
             o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
             return o;
         }
         float4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
         {
             float4 col = _Color * tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
             return float4(2.0f * col.rgb, col.a);
         }
         ENDCG            
     }
 } 
 SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Transparent"}
     Pass {
         Name "BASE"
         SetTexture [_MainTex] {
             constantColor [_Color]
             Combine texture * constant
         } 
     }
 } 

 Fallback "VertexLit"
 }
```

> This shader for outline, 2 pass , first draw above shader and then draw outline and cull the front.

```
Shader "TFTM/Outline/Basic Outline-Alpha" {
     Properties {
         _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (.5,.5,.5,1)
         _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
         _Outline ("Outline width", Range (0, 0.02)) = 0
         _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
     }

 CGINCLUDE
 #include "UnityCG.cginc"

 struct appdata {
     float4 vertex : POSITION;
     float3 normal : NORMAL;
 };
 struct v2f {
     float4 pos : POSITION;
     float4 color : COLOR;
 };

 uniform float _Outline;
 uniform float4 _OutlineColor;

 v2f vert(appdata v) {
     v2f o;
     o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
     float3 norm   = mul ((float3x3)UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, v.normal);
     float2 offset = TransformViewToProjection(norm.xy);
     o.pos.xy += offset * o.pos.z * _Outline;
     o.color = _OutlineColor;
     return o;
 }
 ENDCG
 SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Transparent" }
     UsePass "TFTM/Outline/Basic-Alpha/BASE"
     Pass {
         Name "OUTLINE"
         Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
         Cull Front
         ZWrite On
         ColorMask RGB
         Blend DstColor SrcColor // 2x Multiplicative
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag
         half4 frag(v2f i) :COLOR { return i.color ; }
         ENDCG
     }
 }

 SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Transparent"}
     UsePass "TFTM/Outline/Basic-Alpha/BASE"
     Pass {
         Name "OUTLINE"
         Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
         Cull Front
         ZWrite On
         ColorMask RGB
         Blend DstColor SrcColor // 2x Multiplicative
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma exclude_renderers shaderonly
         ENDCG
         SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine primary }
     }
 }

 Fallback "TFTM/Outline/Basic-Alpha"
 }
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the change logs mention: `Shaders: Per-rendertarget blend modes. New shader syntax: "Blend N Src Dst", "BlendOp N Op", "ColorMask Mask N", where N is the render target index (0..7). This feature works on DX11/12, GLCore, Metal, PS4.` which might affect the shader.

Comment: ya i heard about unity 5.5 change logs but after go through i don't know if it affect the shader above.

Comment: Considering the above quoted change mentions a syntax change for blend, which you do seem to use several times I would assume it does. Then again, I am no hero in shaders.

Comment: i fixed the problem yesterday, but i will go through again because it is better to fix the real problem.

Comment: if you fixed it you should post it as a answer, so that other people with the same problem in the future can be helped as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by changing the api render to `OpenGL ES 3` instead of `Metal`, but of course it is a temporary fix for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
o.pos.xy += offset * o.pos.z * _Outline;
```

The o.pos.z is different depending on platform specific. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PlatformDifferences.html

So, you cannot use it to scale outline.

The purpose of o.pos.z is to keep outline size constant regardless of distance.

Now, what we want is scale value based on camera's z axis.

```
float eye_depth;
// This depth is based on camera's z axis
COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(eye_depth);
// Divided by near plane. This is similar triangle math.
float eye_depth_scale = eye_depth/_ProjectionParams.y; 
o.pos.xy += offset * eye_depth_scale * _Outline;
```

You may want to clamp eye_depth to prevent scaling outline if it's too far.

Comment: For builtin shader variable see this here.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html

For macro download UnityShader and look into UnityCG.cginc